# Object null POST method Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

When I use Postman to test the POST method of my API and I switch to debug mode, the object received by the method is always null

[image]

Here is the code of my DTO :

```
public class CharacterDTO
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And finally the JSON I'm sending with Postman:

```
{
    "FirstName" : "John",
    "LastName" : "Snow"
}
```

If you ever need it, here is the request that Postman makes:

```
POST /api/characters HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:49463
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 1e303be2-f318-4104-b189-5142fa6ddad6
{
    "FirstName" : "John",
    "LastName" : "Snow"
}
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

And the full screenshot of my Postman request :

[image]

Here is the WebApiConfig.cs file :

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

And finally here is the controller :

```
public class CharactersController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/characters
        public IEnumerable<CharacterDTO> GetAllCharacters()
        {
            List<CharacterDTO> list = new List<CharacterDTO>();
            ThronesTournamentManager m = new ThronesTournamentManager();

            foreach (var element in m.GetAllCharacters())
            {
                list.Add(new CharacterDTO(element));
            }
            return list;
        }
        // GET : api/characters/{id}
        public CharacterDTO GetCharacter(int id)
        {
            Character result;
            ThronesTournamentManager m  = new ThronesTournamentManager();
            List<Character> list        = m.GetAllCharacters();

            result = list.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ID == id);

            return new CharacterDTO(result);
        }


        // POST: api/characters
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]CharacterDTO character)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var errors = new List<string>();
                foreach (var state in ModelState)
                {
                    foreach (var error in state.Value.Errors)
                    {
                        errors.Add(error.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, errors);
            }


            ThronesTournamentManager m = new ThronesTournamentManager();
            m.AddCharacter(character.Transform());

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, character);
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your WebAPIConfig here? It worked from my side

Comment: @itsdeft Do you have any action filters in the pipeline that are reading the request body before it reaches the action? The code shown should work for that action.

Comment: @HienNguyen I added the config file in my post ! :)

Comment: @Nkosi What do you mean by pipeline ? I'm not english speaker :/ But if you mean that there is code before this method the answer is no

Comment: Can you post full your api controller here?

Comment: @HienNguyen done ! :)

Comment: what is visual studio version for creating this project?

Comment: @HienNguyen VS Community 2017 version 15.8.7

Comment: Restart your Visual Studio?

Comment: Have you removed the default json serializer by chance?